# C++ method declaration in C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

What will be the C# declaration of the following C++ methods of an unmanaged dll:

```
long WINAPI MT123_GetVersion(HANDLE hComHandle, BYTE *Version, int &len);

long __stdcall MT123_GetStatus(HANDLE hComHandle, BYTE *Saddr, BYTE &status)

long __stdcall MT123_GetTagData(HANDLE hComHandle, BYTE *Saddr,BYTE &status,
BYTE *Data, int &len);
```

with `DllImport` attribute?

Comment: See pinvoke for sample of declarations : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetHandleInformation.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally this:

```
long WINAPI MT123_GetVersion(HANDLE hComHandle, BYTE *Version, int &len);
```

Becomes:

```
int MT123_GetVersion(IntPtr hComHandle, IntPtr pVersionBuffer, ref int len)
```

The `pVersionBuffer` parameter must be initialised using `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem`. You should use `Marshal.Copy` to copy the data to a managed array, then free the buffer using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.

I suggest you write a wrapper function to manage the nitty-gritty. For example

- how much memory do you need to allocate: Is this one where you call the function twice, first time passing `null` to retrieve the length? Or does it have a reasonable maximum size you can hard-code?
- What's the meaning of the return value: Is it an error code you should turn into an exception?

E.g:

```
byte[] GetVersionWrapper(IntPtr hComHandle)
{
    IntPtr pVersionBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
      int len = 0;
      // First retrieve the length
      int status = MT123_GetVersion(hComHandle, IntPtr.Zero, ref len);
      if(status != 0) throw new Exception("message here");
      if(len < 0 || len > 1024) throw new Exception("message here");
      // Now allocate a buffer of the given length.
      pVersionBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(len);
      // Now retrieve the version information into the buffer
      int status = MT123_GetVersion(hComHandle, pVersionBuffer, ref len);
      if(status != 0) throw new Exception("message here");
      // Now copy the version information to a managed array.
      byte[] retVal = new byte[len];
      Marshal.Copy(pVersionBuffer, retVal, 0, len);
      // Return the managed array.
      return retVal;
    }
    finally
    {
      // done in Finally in case anything above throws an exception.
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pVersionBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second argument is simply byte[], no ref.  The len argument passed in must be initialized to the Length of the array.

Comment: @HansPassant If you say so I am sure you are right. I suppose that does the equivalent under the hood, or does it pin the array? I understand pointers better than I understand P/Invoke.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller takes care of pinning arrays that are passed as arguments.  The native code gets a pointer to the first array element.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have tested the code with unmanaged dll from C# but it ways returns -1

Comment: @DuijonNabik you need to check the documentation to find out how you are supposed to use the function. We are guessing since we have not seen this function before.